# Using HTML inside resource files

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, resources

I am developing a standard small [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) website which will be made multilingual using [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) resource files.

My question is about the resource files. See if you have a block of text which should be shown in paragraphs, is it appropriate to add `<p>` tags inside your resource file text?

If not, what would be the best way to deal with it?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use the `@Html.Raw` method inside your view, e.g. `@Html.Raw(STRING FROM RESX FILE HERE)`

Comment: If resource item contains something like this: `<script>alert(1)</script>` this gets executed ... user is shown alert message box. Of course user who edits resources is very careful, but I you can never trust any input.

Answer (score 13):

When I faced the same question I decided against having paragraphs directly in resources. Separate text block by simple new lines (Shift+Enter if I'm not mistaken). Then create a helper method to wrap blocks into paragraphs.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace MyHtmlExtensions
{
  public static class ResourceHelpers
  {
    public static IHtmlString WrapTextBlockIntoParagraphs(this string s)
    {
      if (s == null) return new HtmlString(string.Empty);

      var blocks = s.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" },
                            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

      StringBuilder htmlParagraphs = new StringBuilder();
      foreach (string block in blocks)
      {
        htmlParagraphs.Append("<p>" + block + "</p>");
      }

      return new HtmlString(htmlParagraphs.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your view you import your extension method namespace:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyHtmlExtensions" %>
```

And apply it:

```
<%= Resources.Texts.HelloWorld.WrapTextBlockIntoParagraphs () %>
```

I think it is a more cleaner way than putting markup tags into text resources where they in principle do not belong.

Comment: I like this solution. But, I wonder what kind of affect this has on performance?

Comment: I doubt it can become a bottleneck. Anyway I vote for clarity and maintainability over error-prone micro-optimizations.

Comment: It's not only about paragraphs, what about making a single word in a text bold. Would you write a special markup format just for resource files?

Comment: @Peter, that's outside the scope of your question. Your question was specifically about paragraphs!

Comment: @Marek Grzenkowicz solution is way better.

Answer (score 7):

You can wrap the data for the resx value field in a CDATA block, `<![CDATA[ ]]>`.

e.g.

```
<![CDATA[My text in <b>bold</b>]]>
```

Depending on how you want to use it, you will probably have to strip off the `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` within your app.

This approach allows you to include any html markup in the resx file. I do this to store formatted text messages to be displayed in a jquery-ui dialog from various views within an asp.net mvc app.

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no. Resources are a good place to store localized text and basically this will allow you to send the whole resource to some translation agency who will do all translations for you. So, that's a plus.
However, it also increases the chance of bugs simply because you might forget to encode or decode the HTML. The .resx file is an xml file so it needs to be stored encoded in the resource. (Fortunately, it will encode it automatically.) When you retrieve it again, it will be decoded automatically again. However, if you pass the text to other functions, there is a risk that it will be encoded again, resulting in <b>bold</b> instead of **bold**...
So you will need some additional testing. Which is something you can manage.

But the big problem could be for the person who does the translations. If they just translate the .resx file, they'll see encoded strings. This could be solved if they use something to make the resources more readable. Just as long as they won't translate the tags themselves. They could confuse the persons who will be doing the translations.

Answer (score 5):

You might as well open your resource file in designer and simply type html and text as you wish ..

For example: `Resource Text <b>Data</b>`

However the solution from @Tony Bennett works perfectly..

Also something like this works; the special characters here are use to open/close the triangle brackets of < and >:

```
are you targeting to &lt;b&gt;sustain&lt;/b&gt; the Mark they achieved
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this should be avoided, but sometimes it is practically unavoidable.  Ideally it would be best to store your resources at a level of granularity that allows you to add the presentation markup in common for all languages in the appropriate area of the app.

Sometimes gramatical differences between languages make this difficult.  Sometimes you want to store large chunks of text based resources (large enough that they would have to encompass things like p tags).  It depends a little what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Use URLEncoder to store the HTML string within the resource; then Decode the String and use webview rather than converting all the HTML tags.

> URLDecoder decodes the argument which is assumed to be encoded in the
>   x-www-form-urlencoded MIME content type. '+' will be converted to
>   space, '%' and two following hex digit characters are converted to the
>   equivalent byte value. All other characters are passed through
>   unmodified.
>
> For example "A+B+C %24%25" -> "A B C $%".

Answer (score 0):

We do.

You could use a text-to-HTML converter, but as text contains so much less information than HTML you'd be restricted.