# Should I store markup in resource files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, internationalization, resources

I read this article: [Using HTML inside resource files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491062/using-html-inside-resource-files) but didn't find a satisfactory answer.

Basically, if I wanted to store:

```
<h2>Some heading</h2>
<p>An introduction for a series of steps</p>
<ol>
<li>Do x and y</li>
<li>Do y and z</li>
<li>Final step</li>
</ol>
```

would I put the whole thing into a resource entry or would I create a view that retrieved these values and marked them up?

```
<h2>@MyPage.Header</h2>
<p>@MyPage.Intro</p>
<ol>
<li>@MyPage.Step1</li>
<li>@MyPage.Step2</li>
<li>@MyPage.Step3</li>
</ol>
```

and then, if the final step contained markup like:

```
Make sure to <a href="...">read our disclaimers</a> before continuing...
```

then would I have to write?

```
<li>
@MyPage.Step3MakeSure 
<a href="...">@MyPage.Step3Read</a>
@MyPage.Step3Before
</li>
```

the problem with embedding markup in the resource files is that now a translator needs to know to not touch the markup and if they do you're in trouble... but I can't think of a good structure?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use a templating for javascript such as Mustache or UnderScoreJs... then just load up the data based on a call to a controller action, see demo here for Mustache.
[Mustache Demo](http://mustache.github.io/#demo)

Comment: I don't see how that helps anything.  I still need to decide whether to fragment my content into tiny pieces since it still needs to be stored in resource files